# How to set the converted English text to another textbox using Google Translator Api?

Tags: javascript, translate

I have two text box one for English another for Hindi, when i type in English on first box, the texts should appear as  Hindi version on the second box (on key up event).

I have referred an example [How Can Translate English To Hindi through Google API in Your Website](http://arunsonare.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-can-translate-english-to-hindi.html), and tried to modify the one a bit as per the requirement which is presented below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
</script> 

<script>
function OnLoad() {                

                            var options = {
                                sourceLanguage:
                                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                                destinationLanguage:
                                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
                                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                                transliterationEnabled: true
                            };

                    var control = new
                    google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
                    control.makeTransliteratable(["txtEnglish"]);

    } //end onLoad function

    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

</script> 


</head>
    <body>

       English Text: <input size="40" type="text" id="txtEnglish"/> <br/>
       Hindi Text : <input size="40" type="text" id="txtHindi"/> 

</body>
</html>
```

But this code is working only on the "English Text" textbox. It translates the English words to Hindi only when I press the spacebar on the same.

The requirement is: when user type words in English in English Text box, the English words will remain as it is but on key down event in the English Textbox the converted Hindi version should appear on the Hindi Textbox.

So in no way, the value should get change in the English text box.It should be English only and only the translated Hindi version will appear on the "Hindi Textbox".

I tried like
`document.getElementById("txtHindi").value = document.getElementById("txtEnglish").value;`

but didn't work.

### Edit

I have also placed the output of the solution presented here by @Suresh which is as under

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
</script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function OnLoad() {                
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
        [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    control.makeTransliteratable(["txtHindi"]);
    var keyVal = 32; // Space key
    $("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            var engText = $("#txtEnglish").val() + " ";
            var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
            $("#txtHindi").val($("#txtHindi").val() + engTextArray[engTextArray.length-2]);

            document.getElementById("txtHindi").focus();
            $("#txtHindi").trigger ( {
                type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
            } );
        }
    });

    $("#txtHindi").bind ("keyup",  function (event) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#txtEnglish").val($("#txtEnglish").val() + " "); document.getElementById("txtEnglish").focus()},0);
    });
} //end onLoad function

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script> 

</head>
    <body>
       English Text: <input size="40" type="text" id="txtEnglish"/> <br/>
       Hindi Text`enter code here` : <input size="40" type="text" id="txtHindi"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, ur solution is close but not exactly fitting the requirement. Everytime i press the space bar, the English textbox value also changes... updated the question with the present output

Comment: the above work fine in local. but in production its shows "The page at 'https://myownsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=kamal&ime=transliteration_en_ta&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0je9jagxc'. This request has been blocked;" . and the error line is "google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});". how to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to copy the text from the English field to the Hindi field, and then apply the Google Translate to *the Hindi field only*. Once the text is copied from the English field, there is no reason to manipulate the English field further. Something like:

```
document.getElementById("txtEnglish").addEventListener("keyup", translate);

function translate() {
 document.getElementById("txtHindi").value = document.getElementById("txtEnglish").value;
}
```

At which point Google Translate should change the English text in the `txtHindi` box to Hindi.

EDIT: You'll also want to change your `control.makeTransliteratable(["txtEnglish"]);` to `control.makeTransliteratable(["txtHindi"]);` to produce the translation.

Comment: Google translate does not fire, unless you have focus on that field.

Answer (score 1):

Convert from English (sourceLanguage) to your Langunage, Then Pass your destination language like  Hindi for hi, gujarati for gu,  Type into the editor text will converted to your language

```
      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
          sourceLanguage: 'en',
          destinationLanguage: ['gu'],
          shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
          transliterationEnabled: true
        }
```

Complete Example :

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Google Transliteration API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
          packages: "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
          var options = {
            sourceLanguage: 'en',
            destinationLanguage: ['gu'],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
            transliterationEnabled: true
          }

          // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required options.
          var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

          // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
          var ids = ["language"];
          control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

          // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
          control.showControl('translControl');
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
      </script>

      <form><textarea name="ta"  rows="6"  id="language" cols="6" style="width:600px;height:218px" ></textarea></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Google Transliterate API
    google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
    });

    function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.KANNADA],
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNameInKannada']);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

Comment: This will help u in aspx master pages